# screen toggle windows doesn't work with custom command key

Tags: gnu-screen

I've been using GNU Screen for a while now, but I prefer mapping the command key to something other than `C-a`, as I use that to go to the beginning of a line.  For a while now, I've been running screen with:

```
screen -e^Kk
```

Which sets the command key to `C-k`.  Changing the command key is supposed to also change the command to toggle between screen windows (it should always be the command key, twice), i.e. `C-k C-k`.  This used to work, but after a recent reboot, it doesn't anymore.

Weirdly, if I use `C-j` as my command key, the toggle works fine.  It seems to be a problem with the letter `k`.  But only the toggle command fails.  I can still use:

- `C-k c` - create window
- `C-k A` - rename window
- `C-k n` - switch to next window
- `C-k p` - switch to previous window
- `C-k '` - switch to named/numbered window

So the only thing that fails for me is:

```
screen -e^Kk
C-k C-k  // should switch to most-recently displayed other window
```

I have no idea why this would happen, or what else I can do to troubleshoot it.

I'm running ubuntu, and

```
screen -v
Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06
```

Comment: i have a good suggesstion : use `tmux` : `Terminal MULtiplexer` instead of `screen command`